# Build error Ionic Android : Build failed with an exception

Tags: android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging, ionic-framework

I try to build an ionic app for android and I've this error :

```
What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v4:+.
 Searched in the following locations:
     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml
     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/
 Required by:
     :android:unspecified
```

Android Support Library and Android support Repository are installed.

Thank for your help

EDIT:

I try to update cordova and cordova-cli but it didn't work.

Comment: Upgrade you system, see if it helps. The current *Cordova Tools* version is 5.3.3. Here is a [blog post that should help with the upgrade](http://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/09/22/tools-release.html).

Comment: unless your respond in a message box, I do not know if you have responded. [Forums that support Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/cordova-phonegap-forums.md) ------ [Ionic forum](http://forum.ionicframework.com/)

Comment: Were you able to install the Android Support Library in your SDK Manager?

Comment: I've installed SDK Manager with Android Studio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The location `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/` does not exist anymore (`404`). So the maven configuration seems to be the issue.

I found [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-service-push-client/issues/22) about the same problem you encountered and it was solved by running updating the SDK (which you did already) and readding the Android platform to the Ionic project:

```sh
# Update Android SDK
android list sdk
android update sdk --no-ui --filter extra

# Refresh Ionic Android configuration
ionic platform remove android
ionic platform add android
```

Comment: Before removing the android platform: Be sure to backup any ressources like icons, translations...!

Comment: If above answer not helped please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383323/cant-accept-license-agreement-android-sdk-platform-24/40383457#40383457

Answer (score 2):

Please see my answer in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33184555/cordova-fails-to-build-project/33254592#33254592).

In short: the source of the error maybe an plugin that depends on the com.android.support:support-v4 support library.

If you use cordova >= 5.0.0 update to the new official plugins.