# Can't accept license agreement Android SDK Platform 24

Tags: android, cordova, sdk, licensing

I'm getting the following error when trying to install an android platform on a Cordova project. I've been following this guide: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/

Error occurs when executing the following: $ cordova platform add android --save

> A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>   You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:   [Android SDK Platform 24].

I've searched all over for ways to **accept the license agreement of Android SDK Platform 24**, but no real luck.

Thank you ahead of time.

Comment: for windows, Open SDK Manager with Administrator access. Deselect all,  Find SDK Platform 24, check that, install. There you can accept the license.

Comment: for me the problem was having installed `android-sdk` from multiple places (`brew`, `brew cask` and `android-studio`) and not calling the appropriate `sdkmanager --licenses` command

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically accept all SDK licences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096225/automatically-accept-all-sdk-licences)

Answer (score 172):

You can also just execute

> $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses

Or for Windows execute

> %ANDROID_HOME%/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses

-- OR --

> C:\Users{your-username}\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager --licenses

(credit for windows command to @puneet-kumar)

Comment: On Mac, the sdk is in /Library/Android/

Comment: Worked great for android 26 and 27 as well.  Had the same issue but it happened when my cordova updated gradle from 4.0 to 4.1

Comment: @PuneetKumar this command is not working for me. i have sdkmanager.bat file in tools/bin folder

Comment: in linux -- bash: /tools/bin/sdkmanager: No such file or directory

Comment: Do you have a way of executing that non-interactively?

Comment: None of the command line stuff worked for me on Windows, but going to Tools -> SDK and downloading another SDK prompts you to accept licenses.

Comment: `yes | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses` should be noninteractive.

Comment: In case you installed the SDK via your package manager (like me on Arch), $ANDROID_HOME might be owned by root. My quick workaround was to run `sudo …/sdkmanager --licenses`, instead of chown'ing the whole folder.

Answer (score 166):

I'm not exactly sure how cordova works, but once the licenses are accepted it creates a file. You could create that file manually. It is described on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096225/automatically-accept-all-sdk-licences/38381577#38381577), but here's the commands to create the required license file.

Linux:

```
mkdir "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses"
echo -e "\n8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55" > "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-license"
```

Windows:

```
mkdir "%ANDROID_HOME%\licenses"
echo |set /p="8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55" > "%ANDROID_HOME%\licenses\android-sdk-license"
```

Comment: Hey Mike, from what directory what I execute those commands? Thanks!

Comment: Working directory shouldn't matter, as long as the $ANDROID_SDK environment variable is defined. This may also be $ANDROID_HOME. One of those should be defined; It is the location of the android SDK. You can type 'printenv' and search through the defined variables to find it. Or just 'echo $ANDROID_HOME' to see if it's set. This is assuming linux... windows you would reference the environment variables by %ANDROID_SDK% instead of $ANDROID_SDK.

Comment: Along with the error Cordova will echo the path to ANDROID_HOME (in case you can't find it)!
If ANDROID_HOME is not set you can set it manually like this
`set ANDROID_HOME="C:\Users\*YOUR_USER_NAME*\AppData\Local\Android\sdk"` and the execute the above commands.

Comment: Using Android Studio and installing Android version 24 fixed this issue for me.

Comment: Despite sdk build tools 24 installed. my issue was not resolved on mac machine. Solved this by manually creating licences folder and file android-sdk-license as explained above

Comment: I also tried installing from the SDK manager and it did not resolve the issue. Mike's solution did.

Comment: Works great.  One thing I noticed is that I apparently have 2 different versions of the SDK on my machine, so when I'd accept the license of one, my ANDROID_HOME was the other.  So this fixes it, but the problem is a bit deeper and needs to be fixed, too.

Comment: Looks like another UID is needed for platform and build-tools: `d56f5187479451eabf01fb78af6dfcb131a6481e`. `8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55` still works for Google Repository and Android Support Repository.

Comment: I've tried everything, but for me it is still not working.

Comment: I get permission denied (even with sudo). If I try to execute the command with `sudo su`, then it says >file or directory not found.

Comment: Strange, I suppose you don't have write permission to the directory. Try "sudo chmod -R 777 %ANDROID_HOME%\licenses"

Comment: @Mike its showing me: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/licenses’: Permission denied

Comment: open cmd  as administrator

Answer (score 58):

I had this problem on Mac OS X 10.12.1 with Cordova 6.4.0 and Android Studio 2.2.3.

When I installed Android Studio it installed Platform 25, but not 24. To install 24:

- Open Android Studio.
- Open `Android Studio Menu > Preferences`.
- `Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK`
- Tick the box for `Android 7.0 (Nougat) | 24`
- Click ok and follow the instructions.

Comment: Note: don't forget to adjust android version to SDK platform missing

Comment: I did this, but I probably could've saved a bit of time by clicking "Show Package Details" and selecting only the SDK, rather than installing Google APIs and Source as well.

Comment: Weeks has passed since my last build. re-building my app again I experienced the same issue above but solves it after doing this solution.

Answer (score 31):

The simplest way to solve this issue is to accept the licenses using the following command:

Windows OS:

`C:\Users\{your-username}\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager --licenses`

You will be presented with disclaimers. In order to continue your development efforts, you need to answer 'y' to all disclaimers.

Comment: Man I wish this solution worked. Command runs fine but doesn't fix the error.

Answer (score 27):

I had exactly the same problem. Then i installed "Android 7.0 (API 24) > SDK Platform" and it worked.

[image]

Answer (score 27):

Go to `Android\sdk\tools\bin`

None of the above solutions worked for me and finally this single line accepted all android licences.

```
yes | sdkmanager --licenses && sdkmanager --update
```

Comment: If `windows` users are getting an error. Try `sdkmanager --licenses && sdkmanager --update` and accept the licenses manually.

Comment: For macOs user go to **/Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin**
and ```yes | ./sdkmanager --licenses```.
and ./sdkmanager --help to know more.

Answer (score 17):

In my case I don't use the Android studio (I am using eclipse). I did the following step:
Solved just by running the command

```
android-sdks/tools/bin$ ./sdkmanager --update
```

Which created a `licenses` directory and added a file called `android-sdk-license` inside it.

Then you can run (`licenses` option is not available unless you did the step above)

```
android-sdks/tools/bin$ ./sdkmanager --licenses
```

and accept the license (however, in my case I didn't need to do that)

Comment: I can confirm that this answer works perfectly with the standalone Android SDK Manager, thanks.

Answer (score 13):

I had the issue. You do not need to copy or to create any folder, just be careful of your SDK path. It must be the same of the environnement variable (ANDROID_HOME), which wasn't the same for me. I don't know why.

[image: sdk location]

Answer (score 9):

I installed android sdk build-tools 24(it's current version 24.0.3) through SDK manager.
Path to open SDK manager is shown in img file attached.
This solved my problem
[SDK Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMLBd.png)

Comment: I don't see an attached image, but this worked for me too. There's a button in Android Studio for SDK Manager, and then you can open a standalone SDK manager which will let you pretty easily download all the android 24 stuff

Comment: Again I faced same issue when installing using cordova build in another pc with windows 7 os. This time I had build tools 24 already installed. So followed steps mentioned by Feyyaz below. That is installing Android 7.0 (API 24) and worked. So I feel latest cordova greater than 6 version needs API 24 with build tool 24 or higher version. But I didn't found any documentation for this on their website.

Comment: on MacOS and Linux the SDK manager is at $ANDROID_HOME/tools/android

Answer (score 7):

I had the Android SDK by installing the Android Studio and got this error too. There's a simple solution from [the user guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#download-with-gradle).

1. On a machine with Android Studio installed, click `Tools > Android > SDK Manager`. At the top of the window, note the **Android SDK Location**.
2. Navigate to that directory and locate the `licenses/` directory inside it.

   (If you do not see a `licenses/` directory, return to Android Studio and **update** your SDK tools, making sure to accept the license agreements. When you return to the Android SDK home directory, you should now see the directory.)
3. Copy the entire `licenses/` directory and paste it into the `Android SDK home directory` on the machine where you wish to build your projects.

Answer (score 7):

This error can come if the system is not picking up the ANDROID_HOME environmental variable from the proper path. Make sure you have installed the Android SDK and have set the ANDROID_HOME variable properly to the appropriate path as in the below image:

[ANDROID_HOME_PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2SRm.png)

If the ANDROID_HOME variable is not defined, the system tries to pick the path from a default path(this might not be the path where the Android SDK is defined, leading to this issue).

Answer (score 6):

**Prerequisites**

- Make sure to Java installed
- Have both JAVA and JAVA_HOME paths intialized. [If you have problems setting your JAVA_HOME path, then check this](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/How-to-fix-common-JAVA_HOME-errors-quickly#:%7E:text=One%20very%20common%20developer%20mistake,wrong%20when%20you%20set%20JAVA_HOME.).
- Locate your Android SDK Tools folder.

**Answer**

- Go to `C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin` (Your android SDK Tools folder)
- Run `sdkmanager --licenses`
- It'll ask you to accept whatever the agreements remaining to be accepted. you'll just have to type "y" and enter.
- Will solve the issue

Comment: Tthis is also great if you have a build server that has to auto download sdk's.

Comment: I Tried that and I get `Couldn't load neither find main class com.android.sdklib.tool.SdkManagerCli`. Ideas?

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40718487/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-com-android-uiautomator-uiautomatorview/40843059#40843059. you can try run './SdkManagerCli' inside /sdklib/tools folder.

Answer (score 5):

Install the following component:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I am using Mac and I resolved it using this command:

```
$ which sdkmanager
/usr/local/bin/sdkmanager
$ /usr/local/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
Warning: File /Users/user/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
6 of 6 SDK package licenses not accepted.
Review licenses that have not been accepted (y/N)? y
```

Then I had a list of 6 licenses to accept and its resolved after that.

Answer (score 4):

It is because by default at the time of this writing , **Ionic CLI** tool is defaulted to

```
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="LATEST_SDK_VERSION"/>
```

That is the reason why it complains that you did not accept license agreement , but in reality you did not install the **SDK packages** for that **API** Level yet alone accept the license.

So what you need to do is either

1. Change Your target SDK version
2. Install latest SDK API level from **SDK Manager**

**Changing your SDK version**

You can do it manually and even verify it by running

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

the file can be found at **`your-awesome-app/config.xml`**
open it and add this line , since its hidden as stated above

```
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="24"/>
```

If you are not sure which **API LEVEL Number** you are targeting open **SDK Manager** and look at the **API levels** (Numbers) available on your machine

**Installing Latest SDK Package**

You can add the current **SDK Packages** which the **CLI** is showing , Which in your case it is **24**

Run `SDK MANAGER` as **Admin**

[image: Run SDK Manager as Admin]

Install the **SDK API Packages** which you are targeting

[image: Thats where the SDK API level are written]

How did I know this?
I did it this morning and that's how I solved it and now am playing [Sticky Bubble on Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fadsel.stickybubble) to relax a bit.

Happy Deploying!

Comment: Adding `targetSdkVersion` to `config.xml` file fixed my problem. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

In my case (Dockerfile script to build an Android CI container - https://github.com/menny/docker_android), I had to do these steps:

```
mkdir ~/.android && touch ~/.android/repositories.cfg
yes | sdkmanager --licenses
sdkmanager "build-tools;26.0.0"
sdkmanager "platform-tools" "tools"
sdkmanager "platforms;android-26" "platforms;android-25" "platforms;android-24"
.....
sdkmanager --update
yes | sdkmanager --licenses
```

Two notes:

1. Had to create an empty `repositories.cfg` file or `sdkmanager` would die.
2. Had to perform the fetching/installing of packages in different calls, since there is no progress indication.

Answer (score 4):

You can also follow the "official" way.
Run "**sdkmanager --licenses**" within *tools/bin* folder of Android SDK installation and accept all licenses. Done!

```
c:\android-sdk\tools\bin>sdkmanager --licenses
```

For macOS or Linux it's the same command.

Answer (score 3):

> It needs a ***latest*** stable ***sdk-platform*** installed. I installed SDK-Platform from API 25. It fixed my problem.[image: See Screenshot below]

Answer (score 3):

I had to update the android sdk

```
android update sdk --no-ui
```

at some point it will ask you for license agreement, press `y`. After that you need to remove the angular platform.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to Android SDK location

> C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin

2. Run command `sdkmanager --licenses`
3. Accept the licence for SDK

Comment: The same info has been posted multiple times already. How does yours improve on the existing answers?

Answer (score 2):

This issue is surfacing when already an old version of SDK Manager is in the machine from where the approach of Android build is Changed which requires "android studio". I faced this in Visual Studio that was repeatedly halted with Error Message, "You have not accepted the License for version 25". The solution for this is "Install the Android Studio" and then "go to Environment Variables" and set the ANDROID_HOME to "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk" (This path can be picked from Android Studio, Menu >> Tools >> SDK Manager. Also use the same in "path" of Environment Variables. This way, the new SDK manager is mapped for pickup by Visual Studio Build for Cordova Application.

**This just took my 2 days effort second time**

Wish others don't waste their time in this mess.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the target build might work as referenced [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/you-have-not-accepted-the-license-agreements-of-the-following-sdk-component/69570)

If you want to specify the SDK version you can do so by adding the following line to your config.xml in the root of your ionic / cordova project

```
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to manually re-install sdk 
this help me: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/you-have-not-accepted-the-license-agreements-of-the-following-sdk-component/69570/6

"android update sdk --no-ui --filter build-tools-24.0.0,android-24,extra-android-m2repository"

Answer (score 1):

*Hope this will work for someone out there*
I was facing the same issue! I had 2 sdks, named as sdk and sdk1. It was default linked to sdk but the working one was sdk1.
So I went to Environment Varaible and added
**ANDROID_HOME** and path of the sdk1, i.e. in my case was **C:\Users\tripa_000\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1** , and it solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

For me I was Building the Ionic using "ionic build android" command and I was getting the same problem!
The solution was simply

- To install the required sdk
- Run the same command in CMD must be
  as administrater

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue, and what solved it for me on windows, you are using command line, and you recently installed the android sdk, you must restart Command Prompt or Power Shell after you install the android sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Mike's answer works.But need to put the generated license under C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses.

Answer (score 0):

its mean miss match Android SDK version of cordova with the version you installed. For an example cordova support Android SDK 24 but you don't have Android sdk 24. it may be reverse.

Answer (score 0):

This will update your android SDK and accept the license in the same time (ex for Android 25):

android update sdk --no-ui --filter build-tools-25.0.0,android-25,extra-android-m2repository

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that my ANDROID_HOME variable was being set to another installation I forgot existed. If this is your problem, delete the old installation.

Answer (score 0):

install Android 7 - Platform 24 Full in android sdk manager

just it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid creating the licence folder manually, and in case your sdk is not in the "Users/User" you can go to android studio => Configure => SDK Manager and install any component, i installed the google usb driver from the sdk tools, it automatically generated the license in the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

For those who still have this issue, make sur the Android API of the target version is installed. Check it from the SDK Manager.

Then from the tools/bin folder, you can run *sdkmanager --licenses*