# Ionic build error : You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components: [Android SDK Platform 24]

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, sdk

I'm trying to run the command `ionic build android --release` to build the apk but i am getting this error

> Total time: 1.767 secs Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
>   Error output: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>
>   > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components: [Android SDK Platform 24]. Before building your project,
>   >     you need to accept the license agreements and complete the
>   >     installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK
>   >     Manager. Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license
>   >     agreements from one workstation to another, go to
>   >     http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096225/automatically-accept-all-sdk-licences

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't accept license agreement Android SDK Platform 24](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383323/cant-accept-license-agreement-android-sdk-platform-24)

Comment: Solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383323/cant-accept-license-agreement-android-sdk-platform-24/41279429#41279429

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Install Platform 24 (Android 7) solved this problem

Comment: Worked for Cordova CLI 6.4.0 / Windows 8.1 :) Thanks!

Comment: installed 24 with SDK manager, no luck. I've never had this problem before, just started after uninstalling and reinstalling Ionic+Cordova, etc. Builds worked fine before. Why is it showing up now?

Comment: @mpsyp After Peter Wang's solution when I started the build again I saw android 25 was installed and build succeeded. So maybe installing android 25 may solve the issue.

Comment: This does not always work. The solution by Peter Wang bypasses the possibility of error while the license is still valid.

Answer (score 47):

Install the license:

> mkdir "%ANDROID_HOME%\licenses"
>
> echo |set /p="8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55" >
> "%ANDROID_HOME%\licenses\android-sdk-license"

Comment: I have no %ANDROID_HOME% environment variable.  Tried using %ADT_HOME% instead, no luck.  I'm on Win7.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @mpsyp ANDROID_HOME is your android SDK location. If you don't have it in the windows environment variable, create one and pointing to the folder contains the android sdk package.

Comment: How to do it on windows 7 ?

Comment: This is a good answer. Also please make sure that your android-sdk folder has READ/WRITE permissions given.

Comment: worked for me on Linux. If you don't want to use only command line, make a folder called licenses in Android/sdk/, make the file android-sdk-license, copy 8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55. Thanks Pete!

Answer (score 19):

In Command Prompt, go to ANDROID_HOME\tools\bin

Then run the command, **sdkmanager --licenses**

Accept the licenses you want when it is prompted.

Answer (score 12):

I solved it by installing the Android SDK Platform 24 without the Android SDK manager.

```
android update sdk --no-ui --filter build-tools-24.0.2,android-24,extra-android-m2repository
```

*Cordova CLI 6.4.0 / Windows 10

Comment: This worked for me! Tried both solutions above without success.

Answer (score 7):

1. Go to `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin`
2. Run command `./sdkmanager.bat --licenses`
3. accept license

Worked for me

Comment: At step 1 you forgot "AppData" between username and local (so the path is `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin`), and at step 2, the command I had to execute was `./sdkmanager.bat --licenses`. 

With that, I was able to build for android without issues. 

Thanks for your help. If you accept the edit I send, I think this should be the accepted answer. It focus exactly on where the problem was and solves it.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me under ubuntu :

```
mkdir "$ANDROID_SDK/licenses" || true
echo -e "\n8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55" > "$ANDROID_SDK/licenses/android-sdk-license"
echo -e "\n84831b9409646a918e30573bab4c9c91346d8abd" > "$ANDROID_SDK/licenses/android-sdk-preview-license"
```

source: [Dori's answer to automatically-accept-all-sdk-licences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096225/automatically-accept-all-sdk-licences/38381577)

Answer (score 2):

Above peter wang's answer worked for me after setting the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
in my case `ANDROID_HOME` was `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk`

After that below commands resulted in a successful build.

```
mkdir "%ANDROID_HOME%\licenses"
echo |set /p="8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55" > "%ANDROID_HOME%\licenses\android-sdk-license"
```

Comment: In my case it was only enough to add ANDROID_HOME environment variable, as the license was already there.

Answer (score 2):

My software:

```
Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Gradle 3.5
java version "1.8.0_131"
$ANDROID_HOME = ~/AndroidSDK
```

Working solution:

```
yes | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;25.0.2
```

of course you should use your version of build-tools.

Source:

> [Automatically accept all SDK licences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096225/automatically-accept-all-sdk-licences/38381577)

Answer (score 1):

You will run into an issue like this whenever your Android Studio's packages are outdated, as building will occur in the latest stable releases. To fix, do the following:

**Android Studio > Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK**
*Tick the latest Android versions (or what you need), click Apply.*
It's at this point where Android will ask you to agree to its license(s) and the updated version(s) will be installed.

Now you can Ionic / Cordova / PhoneGap build / run.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having issues coming from a newer version of Android SDK then change your target version in your config.xml.

Next, open Android Studio>Configure>SDK Manager

Check the version you need for 24 use 7.0 and check it. Then install it and try to build again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I used @peters.Wang answer to generate license and placed license folder inside sdk folder.

Thanks to @peters.Wang

[image]

Comment: Just add the image to his answer as this is not a separate solution

Answer (score 0):

Install sdk 25 and accept the license from android studio. That solved my issues.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem with this.

```
mkdir "%ANDROID_HOME%\licenses"

echo |set /p="8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55" > "%ANDROID_HOME%\licenses\android-sdk-license"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow the helper text after

> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components: 
>   in this situation you have to install [Android SDK Platform 24]. in fact the helper text in bracket [] drives you to the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by  checking   file android-sdk-licenses 
 in Installed ANdroid  path for ex my path G:\Android\sdk\licenses 
with the same file present in this directory
C:\Users\Ashutosh\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\licenses copy all the licenses if more than one :)

Answer (score 0):

I had same situation and all of the above suggestion did not work because either my installation and component folder names are different or the files are in different places.

I had old installation of Android Studio in C and new in E. I had uninstalled the old version but Android studio did not clear all files and reset my Env. Variable. So I simply did following

1) Searched for this file: android-sdk-license

2) See if above file is in folder Licenses surrounded by other folders like add-ons, build-tools, emulator etc.

3) Then make sure ANDROID_HOME is pointing  to this parent folder of Licenses.

Answer (score 0):

Please visit https://discuss.circleci.com/t/licences-for-android-build-tools-not-accepted/17285/18

dependencies:

override:

```
echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-26.0.2,android-26
```

instead of my original:

dependencies:

override:

```
echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-26.0.2
```

Answer (score -2):

Install the latest Android Studio and accept the license agreement.

https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html