# Error In Ionic Build Android - build.gradle error

Tags: gradle, ionic-framework, ionic2, build.gradle

Getting error on running command.. **ionic build android**

Please check image below..

[image]

Comment: add one empty directory in your android folder and then place the accepted licenses key inside that direcotry this did the trick for me

Comment: From where do I get 'accepted licenses key' ??

Comment: Just checking the obvious - have you done what the message says and upped the gradle version? I've not had this message before, but it looks very like your gradle version is too old to read the build file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40392345/ionic-build-error-you-have-not-accepted-the-license-agreements-of-the-followin @AnkitMaheshwari