# Cordova license agreements of SDK components

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

After created new cordova project on Ubuntu, i've this error message on build project :

```
Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=/usr/lib/android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
studio
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (24.0.0) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (26.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.1.
Android SDK Build Tools 26.0.2 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
Observed package id 'build-tools;24.0.0' in inconsistent location '/usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/debian' (Expected '/usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/24.0.0')
Already observed package id 'build-tools;24.0.0' in '/usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/24.0.0'. Skipping duplicate at '/usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/debian'
Observed package id 'build-tools;24.0.0' in inconsistent location '/usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/debian' (Expected '/usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/24.0.0')
Already observed package id 'build-tools;24.0.0' in '/usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/24.0.0'. Skipping duplicate at '/usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/debian'
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2 in /usr/lib/android-sdk/licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 27 in /usr/lib/android-sdk/licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 27 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  [Android SDK Platform 27, Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2].
```

The `sdkmanager --licenses` command is already running and all accepted : **All SDK package licenses accepted.======] 100% Computing updates...**

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic build error : You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components: \[Android SDK Platform 24\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40392345/ionic-build-error-you-have-not-accepted-the-license-agreements-of-the-followin)

Comment: In System Settings, i don't have SDK Manager

Comment: it's part of the SDK... even `notepad.exe` should suffice to create a text file.

Comment: I don't know what file i need :/