# Error in the creation of my apk in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

**I want to create the apk of my project for android and uninstall cordova and I installed it again but it marks me the following error**

*He added the error that I get*

> Total time: 16.805 secs Subproject Path: CordovaLib Subproject Path:
>   app Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
>   publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All
>   variants are now published. File
>   C:\Users\victorc.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
>   Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 27 in
>   C:\Users\victorc\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses Warning: License
>   for package Android SDK Platform 27 not accepted.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
>
>   > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:   [Android SDK Platform 27].   Before building your
>   >     project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the
>   >     installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK
>   >     Manager.   Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license
>   >     agreements from one workstation to another, go to
>   >     http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 52s cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
>
>   > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:   [Android SDK Platform 27].   Before building your
>   >     project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the
>   >     installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK
>   >     Manager.   Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license
>   >     agreements from one workstation to another, go to
>   >     http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 52s [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess
>   cordova.
>
> ```
>     cordova build android exited with exit code 1.
>
>     Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
> ```
>
> C:\Users\victorc\Documents\Proyectos\AppIonic>

Comment: Have you tried any solutions from this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40392345/ionic-build-error-you-have-not-accepted-the-license-agreements-of-the-followin?rq=1

Comment: You can also automatically accept all the licences while installing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096225/automatically-accept-all-sdk-licences

Comment: Manage to solve with the following command: cordova platform rm android,

cordova platform add android