# Ionic 4 compile error with android, problems with licences

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I try to compile my app, with ionic 4, with these commands:

```
ionic cordova prepare android 
ionic cordova build android
```

and I get an error:

> What went wrong:
>   A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
>   You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
>   [Android SDK Platform 27].
>   Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.

How can I fix it?

My OS: Windows 10, ionic 4, Android Pie

Comment: [**Solution here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40392345/ionic-build-error-you-have-not-accepted-the-license-agreements-of-the-followin)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic build error : You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components: \[Android SDK Platform 24\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40392345/ionic-build-error-you-have-not-accepted-the-license-agreements-of-the-followin)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Android Studio-->Tools-->SDK Manager and then add an android SDK platform 27 or higher, accept the license and let it download and everything should work from there on.