# ionic build android show this error * Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, sdk

I have already installed the sdk, and also added `JAVA_HOME` but why do I get this error, when I run `ionic build android`?

> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
>   [Android SDK Platform 24].
>   Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
>   Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
>
> Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383323/cant-accept-license-agreement-android-sdk-platform-24

Comment: improved formating

Answer (score 0):

This error really mean you are missing a component needed to make the build. In this case you can install missing Android SDK Platform 24 with the following command in the console:

```
android update sdk --no-ui --filter android-24
```

Or by going to the SDK manager and installing the package manually