# Error: Could not find or load main class com.android.uiautomator.UiAutomatorViewer

Tags: android, android-studio, automation

I am trying to run Android's UiAutomatorViewer on ubuntu system but when i run this command `uiautomatorviewer`  it gives this error: `Error: Could not find or load main class com.android.uiautomator.UiAutomatorViewer` I have set path to .bashrc file:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/rahulsharma/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

When i run other program of tools folder like sdk manager, that executes successfully.
Does anyone know where i am doing mistake?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could not find the reason that why i am getting this error but found solution. To start UiAutomatorViewer:

- Open terminal
- In terminal go to tools folder inside android sdk
- run `./uiautomatorviwer` command.

Ui Automator Viwer is running now.
May be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the `uiautomatorviewer` is located inside `<android-sdk>/tools/bin`

1. Open terminal, go to `<android-sdk>/tools/bin`
2. run `./uiautomatorviewer`

Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty similar way in recent version of Windows, while e.g. %ANDROID_HOME% is declared in PATH as %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk then simply run:

cd %ANDROID_HOME%/tools/bin

uiautomatorviewer.bat