# Ionic run error: Android SDK missing license agreements

Tags: android, macos, ionic-framework, android-sdk-tools

I have an Ionic project running in Mac and when I run the command  `ionic run android` I get this

> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
>     [Android SDK Platform 24, Android SDK Build-Tools 25.0.1].
>     Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.

I had run the following commands but they hadn't solve the problem

- `android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-23.0.1,android-23,extra-android-m2repository`
- `android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-24.0.1,android-24,extra-android-m2repository`
- `android update sdk -a --filter platform-tools,build-tools-21.0.1,android-21,extra-android-m2repository --no-ui --force`

I don´t know what platform-tools is missing, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate `android-sdk-license` file and store it in `%ANDROID_HOME%--->licenses` folder. Just do this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/40383457/6554634 as per your Operating system.

Step1: Create `android-sdk-license` open it and copy this `8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55`

Step2: Store it in `%ANDROID_HOME%--->licenses` folder

Comment: I already have that file and it has the same string, but the Error is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The license can be read and accepted over the terminal. Just execute

> $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses

If you only create a File you haven't accept the license. So this is the better way.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45139795/6752349