# Unable to run Cordova project on Android from IntelliJ

Tags: android, cordova, intellij-idea

This is my first time to make a web app via cordova. The problem is when I try to run it on android the following error shows up. I believe that I have installed and updated the android SDK to the latest and should have agreed to the license before installing the updates. I've googled around for a clear solution but can not find a simple solution. What procedure and steps should I take to solve this issue? I would love to hear some simple clear tips for dummies like me from you! I would love to hear from you.

```
 * What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  [Android SDK Platform 25].
  Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Comment: So, you have already checked all the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383323/cant-accept-license-agreement-android-sdk-platform-24) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096225/automatically-accept-all-sdk-licences) and it didn't help?

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work. Maybe I should reinstall the Android SDK and set up from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

If you install Android SDK through the SDK manager in Android studio, it will prompt you to accept the license agreements. after you do this you should be able to prepare and run your project.