# gitlab pipelines configure the gitlab-ci.yml file

Tags: android, gitlab, pipeline

I work in Android Project, I use gitlab.
I config gitlab-ci.yml file and I try to commit my Android Project but i have an issue in the gitLab pipeline.
I migrating my code and i'm trying to build my application but I receive erro below:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>     You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
>     [ConstraintLayout for Android 1.0.2, Solver for ConstraintLayout 1.0.2].
>     Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
>     Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 2 mins 8.129 secs
>   ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

this is my gitlab-ci.yml file

```
image: openjdk:8-jdk
variables:
ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "25"
ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "25.0.2"
ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS: "24.4.1"
before_script:
 - apt-get --quiet update --yes
 - apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
 - wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.tgz https://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}-linux.tgz
 - tar --extract --gzip --file=android-sdk.tgz
 - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}
 - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter platform-tools
 - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}
 - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-android-m2repository
 - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-google-google_play_services
 - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-google-m2repository
 - export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/android-sdk-linux
 - export PATH=$PATH:$PWD/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/
 - chmod +x ./gradlew
stages:
 - build
 - test
build:
 stage: build
 script:
 - ./gradlew assembleDebug
artifacts:
 paths:
  - app/build/outputs/
 unitTests:
stage: test
script:
 - ./gradlew test
functionalTests:
 stage: test
 script:
  - wget --quiet --output-document=android-wait-for-emulator https://raw.githubusercontent.com/travis-ci/travis-cookbooks/0f497eb71291b52a703143c5cd63a217c8766dc9/community-cookbooks/android-sdk/files/default/android-wait-for-emulator
- chmod +x android-wait-for-emulator
- echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter sys-img-x86-google_apis-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}
- echo no | android-sdk-linux/tools/android create avd -n test -t android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK} --abi google_apis/x86
- android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator64-x86 -avd test -no-window -no-audio &
- android update sdk --no-ui --filter build-tools-25.0.2,android-25,extra-android-m2repository
- ./android-wait-for-emulator
- adb shell input keyevent 82
- ./gradlew cAT
artifacts:
paths:
- app/build/reports/androidTests/
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't accept license agreement Android SDK Platform 24](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383323/cant-accept-license-agreement-android-sdk-platform-24)

Comment: my project build correctly in Android Studio, I don't use cordova, my problem is when i commit my project in gitlab, i recive this build error.

Comment: Have you tried the fix mentioned in the linked thread?

Answer (score 0):

add the following lines to end of `before_script` section

```
  - export SDK_MANAGER="${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/bin/sdkmanager --sdk_root=${ANDROID_HOME}"
  - set +o pipefail
  - echo y | ${SDK_MANAGER} --licenses
  - set -o pipefail
```

a full before_script might looks like this

```
variables:
  ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "28"
  ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "28.0.3"
  ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS:   "6609375_latest"

before_script:
  - echo ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK ${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}
  - echo ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS ${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}
  - echo ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS ${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}
  - apt-get --quiet update --yes
  - apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
  - wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}.zip
  - unzip -d android-sdk-linux android-sdk.zip
  - export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$PWD/android-sdk-linux
  - export SDK_MANAGER="${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/tools/bin/sdkmanager --sdk_root=${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}"
  - echo y | ${SDK_MANAGER} "platforms;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}" >/dev/null
  - echo y | ${SDK_MANAGER} "platform-tools" >/dev/null
  - echo y | ${SDK_MANAGER} "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}" >/dev/null
  - export PATH=$PATH:${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/platform-tools/
  - chmod +x ./gradlew
  # temporarily disable checking for EPIPE error and use yes to accept all licenses
  - set +o pipefail
  - echo y | ${SDK_MANAGER} --licenses
  - set -o pipefail
```