# Why can't I run my Cordova Project in Android?

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, android-sdk-manager

I am trying to run my Cordova Project in a Android platform on a Mac.
I downloaded Android Studio.

However, whenever I try to run the following command line in terminal

```
cordova run android
```

it ends in the following error:

```
BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.391 secs
Error: /Users/karel/Cordova Projects/demo/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  [Android SDK Platform 25].
  Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Am I missing something?
It works for

```
cordova run ios
cordova run osx
cordova run browser
```

How can I accept these terms the message is talking about? I recall accepting to certain terms, at least, when downloading Android Studio.

I am wondering whether I have to install Android SDK separately from Android Studio or something. (I have no experience with Android).

Thanks for your time. Your help would mean a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't accept license agreement Android SDK Platform 24](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383323/cant-accept-license-agreement-android-sdk-platform-24)

Comment: @GlobalRationality Install android sdk version 25 and accept its license during installation