# App Shortcuts for cordova application

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, android-appshortcut

I am trying to include [cordova-plugin-shortcuts-android](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-shortcuts-android) in the application but i am not able to build the application.

below is the screeshot of the error

[image]

Is there any other equivalent plugin which can be included in the application and also is there any plugin which can be used in IOS for the same reqirement.

After **updating android SDK** but still I get this error, I have added the screen shot of the error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the version you have on your android SDK for example

```
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23"/>
```

Maybe the plugin requires a new sdk , more info see this thread -> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383323/cant-accept-license-agreement-android-sdk-platform-24/40383457#40383457)

Comment: Hi @Kevin, I have updated the android SDK bu still get the error. I have updated the post with the error.
Or is it problem with the plugin which I am using? When I add the plugin I get the error but when the plugin is not part of the project I don't get the error.

Comment: @ShashankHS this plugin only works iff your app targets Android 7.1 (API level 25) or higher. see those link: [link 1](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platforms.html)  [link 2](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts.html)

Comment: I have target SDK set as 26 and trying to test it on an Android device with Android version 8 (API level 26), but still I get the same error. I have also installed SDK tools for version 25, 26 via SDK Manager.