# Android Studio (Xamarin) start up and then just shut down. How do i get it running?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-emulator

I'm just in the starting phase of learning how to make apps with c# xamarin forms to make cross plattform apps. I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and i've installed Xamaring through Visual Studio Installer. When i've created a project and try to start the android project through a Android Emulator, Android Device Manager just start and then shut down without starting any emulator.

When i go to Android SDK Manager it is nothing there. I then went to Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android Settings 
and under Android SDK Location is says
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
Everytime i start Visual Studio i need to agree to Android SDK licens and even if i click Accept it says waiting for licens agreement down to the left.
So i tried accept everyting like this in the console %ANDROID_HOME%/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
which they recommended here
[Can't accept license agreement Android SDK Platform 24](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383323/cant-accept-license-agreement-android-sdk-platform-24)

The code i try to run when it doesntwork is this(I actually dont think that matter though)

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace test3.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "test3", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

When i try to run the code it just says 
"The debug was canceled. Please create an android emulator to debug the application."
But since i cant start Android device manager i cant to that.

Comment: Have you added the path of Sdk to Environment Variables of you PC.

Comment: Did that but nothing changed.